# AWS S3API move files from a folder to another within the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need perform a sort of command like :

> aws s3api copy-object --copy-source bucket-1 --key *.txt --bucket
>   bucket-1/folder/

I have many txt files in the root of the bucket and I want to move them to a folder within the same bucket.

thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the high-level `s3` api:

`aws s3 mv s3://bucket/object.txt s3://bucket/folder/object.txt`

However, you would need to specify the full object name - wildcards don't work.

You could use a script to iterate over the bucket contents, with the Linux `cut` command to extract the object name, before executing the `aws s3 mv` operation on each object name. Save the below as `script.sh`:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   IFS=$'\n'
   while read LINE; do
     OBJECT=`echo $LINE | cut -d ' ' -f 5`
     aws s3 mv s3://bucket/$OBJECT s3://bucket/folder/
   done < objects.txt
```

The above reads each line from the `objects.txt` file, `cuts` the line to only the object key field (aka filename), and then passes that field to the `aws s3 mv` command.

Then you'd run that like so:

```
   chmod +x script.sh // remember to make the script executable
   aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ > objects.txt
   ./script.sh
```

Note that if you have hundreds of text files, this may result in throttling on your S3 bucket. If you have that many files, I would advise you to add a small delay in the `while` loop above, to ensure that you are sending less than 100 requests per second.

A 20ms delay would mean that you send 50 requests to S3 per second. It may take several seconds to execute completely in that case, but that should be acceptable, considering that this is a once-off operation.

**EDIT** Important! You probably want to add a check in the while loop, to ensure that the filename ends in `.txt` before executing the `mv`. That will ensure that you only move the text files.

Comment: can I use something like `mv s3://bucket/*.txt s3://bucket2/*.txt` ?

Comment: No, you can't use wildcards (`*`).

Comment: SO mandatory I must to create a loop and go thru the loop moving one by one ? wow

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.